# Setup a flag I or U for the Databricks delta merge

Tags: apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

Is there a way I can setup the flag column(I-inserted, U-updated), when I perform the delta merge logic. I'm curious to know how many records got inserted and how many records got updated in the daily delta merge logic.

My sample dataframe:

```
df_latest = spark.createDataFrame(
[
  ('Java', "20000"),  # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
  ('Scala', '90000'),
  ('Python', '100000')
],
["language", "users_count"]  # add your column names here
)
```

When i perfrom the below delta merge logic, I will need to a have one more column called flag with (I or U), describing on the version02 of the delta table how many rows got inserted and how rows got updated.

```py
test_delta.alias("h")\
  .merge(df_latest.alias("df"), "h.language = df.language")\
  .whenMatchedUpdateAll()\
  .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()\
  .execute()
```

Any help would be appreciated, couldn't figure this out myself..!!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a similar technique and stumbled on your question. Luckily, I was able to solve it using the approach described below:

1-) Create a Delta Table and Define it's schema.

```
from delta import *

DeltaTable.createIfNotExists(spark) \
    .addColumn("language",StringType())\
    .addColumn("users_count",IntegerType())\
    .addColumn("Flag",StringType())\
    .property("description", "Testing Flag Logic") \
    .location("/mnt/output/TestingFlagLogic") \
    .execute()
```

A snapshot of the table can be seen on the link below
[Snapshot of the DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hso4g.png)

2-) Use The below Command For Insertion to the Table.

```
from delta.tables import *

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark,"/mnt/output/TestingFlagLogic")

deltaTable.alias("Destination")\
.merge(
    df.alias("Updates"),
    "Destination.language = Updates.language")\
  .whenMatchedUpdate(set =
    {
      "language": "Updates.language",
      "users_count": "Updates.users_count",
      "Flag": F.lit("U")
    }) \
  .whenNotMatchedInsert( values =
    {
      "language": "Updates.language",
      "users_count": "Updates.users_count",
      "Flag": F.lit("I")
    }) \
  .execute()
```

3-) After the First Insertion, you would get the below DataFrame, It would have a Flag Column Populated with the value "I".
[Delta Table After First Insertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPDum.png)

4-) The You define a new DataFrame with the values which you would want to update.Here I am doubling the User Count of the languages "Python" and "C++".

```
df_updated = spark.createDataFrame(
[
  ('Python', '200000'),
  ('C++', '300000'),
],
["language", "users_count"]  # add your column names here
)
```

[Snapshot of the Dataframe which has the values to update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu9Al.png)

5-) Now Insert using the same logic described in step 2. Just change df with df_updated.

```
from delta.tables import *

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark,"/mnt/output/TestingFlagLogic")
deltaTable.alias("Destination")\
.merge(
    df_updated.alias("Updates"),
    "Destination.language = Updates.language")\
  .whenMatchedUpdate(set =
    {
      "language": "Updates.language",
      "users_count": "Updates.users_count",
      "Flag": F.lit("U")
    }) \
  .whenNotMatchedInsert( values =
    {
      "language": "Updates.language",
      "users_count": "Updates.users_count",
      "Flag": F.lit("I")
    }) \
  .execute()
```

6-) Congrats, you have successfully achieved the mentioned functionality.
Now query your delta and display it for a visual verification.

```
df_new = spark.read.format("delta").load("/mnt/output/TestingFlagLogic")
display(df_new)
```

A snapshot of the delta table after update can be seen on the link below.
[Snapshot of the Updated Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYEMo.png)

You can see that "Python" and "C++" have an updated user count value along with the "Flag" values as "U" as it was an Upsert(Update+Insert) operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need metrics, then you can retrieve that information from the history of the table (either via [DESCRIBE HISTORY](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#retrieve-delta-table-history) SQL command, or via [history function](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/python/index.html#delta.tables.DeltaTable.history)).  Both of them are returning the dataframe that contains [operation metrics](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#operation-metrics-keys) (the `operationMetrics` column that is a map), and for MERGE operation there are metrics that describe how many rows where inserted/updated/deleted: `numTargetRowsInserted`, `numTargetRowsUpdated`, `numTargetRowsDeleted`.

Something like this (only for last version - if you need for all, then just remove `1` from history call):

```
from delta.tables import *

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forName(spark, "mytable")
df = deltaTable.history(1)
f.select(df["operationMetrics"]["numTargetRowsInserted"],
         df["operationMetrics"]["numTargetRowsUpdated"],
         df["operationMetrics"]["numTargetRowsDeleted"])
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ott, but some reason it's not working , i'm getting 'null' on operationMetrics[numTargetRowsInserted], operationMetrics[numTargetRowsUpdated], operationMetrics[numTargetRowsDeleted]

Comment: do you get anything from `df = deltaTable.history(1)` - what `df.show(truncate=False)` returns?

Comment: df = deltaTable.history(1) -- getting version=05 row. but operationMetrics attribute value is NULL.

Comment: Hello @AlexOtt, the reason I cannot see number of updates, inserts and deletes is because I'm on the Databricks runtime version 6.4. I need to be on the runtime version >6.4. I've test cluster which is  running on 7.2, there I could see the number of updates, deletes & inserts, Thanks for your help much appreciated.